# Why do we multiply x - intercepts when creating polynomial equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, polynomials

I understand polynomials and the fact that the solutions to a polynomial equation
$ P(x) = x^n+ x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}......$  would be the x intercepts on a normal x-y graph. One question I've always had was why do we multiply the roots to create a equation? This is something I never cared to understand now that i think of it , why would we multiply the roots?

Comment: If I understand what you wanted to say, we don't multiply roots, we multiply binomials whose roots are the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @RonComputing Are you asking why we do $(x-a)(x-b) = 0$ to find that the roots are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Well look it the other way round: let  $P(x)$ be a polynomial such that $P(x_0)=0$. We know that $x-x_0$ evaluates to $0$ when $x=x_0$, so we can divide $P(x)$ by $x-x_0$ and write $P(x)=P_1(x)(x-x_0)$. Do this for all the roots and you have your decomposition.

Comment: @AndrewLi  like if we had $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ why would we take the product to create one overall polynomial?

Comment: @RonComputing I don't understand. Nobody's telling you have to expand that expression out. We *factor* polynomials to find roots via the Null Factor Law.

Comment: @AndrewLi         if we had a graph , x-y plane  we drew a parabola  that intercepts the -3 and 3 points on the x axis , this will result in us writing the following $x-3$ and $x+3$  this overal will be $p(x)=(x-3)(x+3)$ why isnt the equation written as $p(x) = (x-3) + (x+3)? The only part i really want to understand guys is why do we take the product , instead of lets say the sum.. i just want a deep logical explanation

Comment: @RonComputing Because (in part) due to the Null Factor Law. As you mentioned, x = -3 and 3 are on the x-axis. That means $f(x) = 0$ at $x=\pm 3$. If we used $(x+3)+(x-3)$ and plugged in $3$ or $-3$, would you get $0$? How about $(x-3)(x+3)$? The whole point is this: say we have a product $xy$. If either $x$ or $y$ is $0$, the overall product $xy$ is $0$. Same idea applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that for equation of form y=x^n+x^n-1 etc...
The roots are values of x for which y=0. If Kn denotes the nth root .then the equation can be recasted in the form of products. Like y= (x-k1)(x-k2) etc..
* Because if this product form was not possible then y won't be equal to zero when x=kn .